# How to find sum of equation from 1 to N

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I understand that the sum of n from $1$ to $n$ is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. I'm trying to figure out the sum from $1$ to $n$ of the following expression $\frac{L(n-1)}{R}$ where $L$ and $R$ are unknown variables. To do this would I just do $\frac{L(n-1)}{R} \times \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ?

Comment: It would improve your Question to refer to $L(n-1)/R$ as an *expression* rather than an equation (since it is not one).

Comment: Agree with @hardmath (+1). You can't add equations, even if you had furnished equations. You can add expressions and produce a new equation of the corresponding sums. But equations aren't involved here.

Comment: Interesting, I never made the distinction between the two before. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pull out the constant factor of $\frac LR$ to give:

$$
\frac LR \sum_{i=1}^n (i-1).
$$

Now note that the sum above is equivalent to taking the sum of $i$ from $1$ to $n-1$, so this gives:

$$
\frac LR \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i = \frac{L(n-1)n}{2R}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

So you're looking for $\frac{L*((1)-1)}{R}+\frac{L*((2)-1)}{R}+...+\frac{L*((n-1)-1)}{R}+\frac{L*((n)-1)}{R}$

This simplifies to $\frac{L}{R}*(0)+\frac{L}{R}*(1)+...+\frac{L}{R}*(n-2)+\frac{L}{R}*(n-1) = \frac{L}{R}*(1+2+...+(n-2)+(n-1))$

Answer (score 0):

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac{L(i-1)}{R} = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{L}{R}i-\frac{1}{R}\right)=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{L}{R}i\right) - \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{R}\right) = \frac{L}{R}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni\right)-\frac{1}{R}\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n1\right)=\dots$

From here, as you correctly noted above, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$

You should also be aware that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 1 = n$

Use these to simplify what are still in the parenthesis above and complete the problem.